# Create a re-usable type writer effect function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I know the basics of what I need to do here, but my attempt at coding it is riddled with problems so here is what I want to do.

Define a series of strings to be called up into a function that types it onto the screen with a slight delay between each letter.
I've found some examples of people making typewriter title cards, but these are not designed to be used like functions that can be called up on the fly. For this particular project, we need the text to function like a makeshift dialog system that won't be called up until the function is called with a specific string.
Like a button with `" onclick="dialogFunction(idOfStringToBeTyped) "`
what I have looks like this:

```
var d1Example = "Hello, I am example dialog";

function dialog(dialogString) {
    var i;
for (i = 0; i <= dialogString.length(); i++) { 
    document.write( dialogString.charAt(i) );
     java.lang.Thread.sleep(50);
}}
```

So my attempts to code the content has been... brute force-y...

EDIT: to include my attempt, should have been there in the first place, sorry about that.

This, in theory, should work, but in practice does nothing. I probably have a syntax error. but really it doesn't make sense to me why this doesn't work.

Comment: Why didn't you include your "brute force-y" method? It would be helpful to understand what you're missing/doing wrong. Have you looked into using `Thread.sleep(ms)` in your loop?

Comment: Are you sure you're writing Java? Everything except `String d1Example` looks more like JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As it stands, this looks like you are asking us to write the missing code for you, which is considered off-topic here. Please visit the [help] and especially read [ask].

Comment: Hi! I've updated the post, sorry about that. I will certainly do better in the future. My intention is to see what methods people would recommend, not to ask for free coding labor.

Comment: @AuxTaco - agreed, but `String d1Example` _really_ doesn't look like JavaScript...

Comment: Yup, that's an error I caught just after making the post, I'll update the post right now.

Comment: So is this Java or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the JavaScript functions `setTimeout` and `Math.random()`.

You can use `Math.random()` to create a floating point integer between 0 and 1.

```
var multipule = 5
var rand = Math.random();  // 0.5680401974599227
var randInSeconds = rand * multipule // 2.840200987299614
var waitInSeconds = Math.round(randInSeconds) // 3
```

Then use the the `setTimeout` out method to call the code that writes each character.  `setTimeout` takes two parameters, a function and the number of seconds:

```
var writeCharacter = function(){
  ... 
};

setTimeout(writeCharacter, 300);
```

I'll leave it to you to work out all the timing.